# How do I run a stage in Jenkins only on pull request?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkinsfile-based pipeline with several stages in it right now that is triggered by webhook on every commit to Github. I'd like to keep the "build" and "unit tests" stages running on every commit, but ONLY run the "integration tests" stage when the branch is up for pull request.

What I want:

```
stage("build)"{
    // runs every commit
}
stage("unit tests"){
    // runs every commit
}
stage("integration tests"){
    // runs ONLY on pull request
}
```

I've been unable to find a solution to this, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I found very easy way for declarative pipeline without any plugins and can be used anywhere.

```
        stage (' PR check ') {
        when {
                branch 'PR-*'  
            }

            steps {
            sh '''
            echo "PULL REQUEST CHECK IS DONE HERE"
            '''

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

After asking in the #jenkins IRC channel I was pointed in the right direction. This is possible using the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Filter+Branch+PR+Plugin

Scripted pipeline:

```
if(env.CHANGE_ID) {
// do something because it's a pull request
} else {
// not a pull request
}
```

Declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
stages {
    stage('Example Deploy') {
        when {
            allOf {
                environment name: 'CHANGE_ID', value: ''
                branch 'master'
            }
        }
        steps {
            // not a pull request so do something
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I would use the the built-in condition of Jenkins `changeRequest()`.

```
stage ("sample") {
    when {
        anyOf {
            changeRequest()
            branch BRANCH_MAIN
        }
    steps {
            // not a pull request so do something
    }
   }

}
```

Doc: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stages